# Google tag manager is missing "Click Elements"

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up GTM to count clicks but the required trigger functionality is missing. There should be an option to fire on "Click Element" but I don't have it. Please see screen garb attached.

Question: Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the relevant variables (Variables / Built-in Variables / Configure and then mark the checkbox where it says "Click Element").

[image]